# ¿Como desactivar focusOut cuando hago un keyDown.enter en Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

lo que ocurre es que tengo un campo de texto en el que cuando presiono enter o dejo el focus fuera del campo, se realiza una consulta. El problema es que si presiono enter se llama al método dos veces.

He intentado usar `stopImmediatePropagation()`, `preventDefault()` y `stopPropagation()` para que no se llame el focus out, pero no he tenido éxito.

En mi html tengo este Input:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control w-75 d-inline float-right" #Identificacion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="identificacionFuncionario"
                      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ng-pattern="/^-?[0-9][^\.]*$/" (keydown.enter)="buscarFuncionario($event)" (focusout)="buscarFuncionario($event)">
```

Y este es el método que tengo en mi componente:

```
buscarFuncionario(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(event.type == 'keydown'){
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    //Preparo datos y hago la consulta
}
```

Ya verifiqué que si este entrando en el if únicamente cuando le doy enter pero no se que puedo hacer para evitar este comportamiento.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir una bandera, por ejemplo `cargandoFuncionario = false`. Cuando una de los eventos se ejecute compruebas y cambias el estado así:

```javascript
cargandoFuncionario = false

buscarFuncionario(event) {
    

    if(cargandoFuncionario) return alert("Ya se esta ejecutando")
    this.cargandoFuncionario = true
    //Preparo datos y hago la consulta


    //Termina operacion asincrona

    tuOperacion.subscribe(resultado=> {
       //...Operaciones con el resultado
       this.cargandoFuncionario = false
    }, error=> this.cargandoFuncionario = false)

}
```